# How can I make expandable cite list?

Tags: citing, expansion, xstring

I try to make a cite list, which usable with `xstring`. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\citelist}{m}
  {%
    \@for\citeitem:={#1}\do{\@nameuse{b@\citeitem}, }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

`\citelist{a,b}'

\StrChar{\citelist{a,b}}{1}[\temp]

`\meaning\temp'  (instead of `macro:->A')

\begin{thebibliography}{A}
\bibitem[A]{a} A
\bibitem[B]{b} B
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunatelly `\citelist` does not work with `\StrChar`. What can I do?

Comment: What would be a sensible usage for this?

Comment: @egreg I would like to insert an automatic Hungarian definite article in front of the reference, which depends on the characters of the reference.

Comment: Please, make a new question with the details of the actual problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\@for` uses assignments, which are not expandable. A recursive definition should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\citelist}[1]{\@citelist#1,\relax,}
\newcommand*{\@citelist}{}% better safe than sorry
\def\@citelist#1,{\ifx#1\relax\else\@nameuse{b@#1}, \expandafter\@citelist\fi}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

`\citelist{a,b}'

\StrChar{\citelist{a,b}}{1}[\temp]

`\meaning\temp'  (instead of `macro:->A')

\begin{thebibliography}{A}
\bibitem[A]{a} A
\bibitem[B]{b} B
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I need.